# Quick question about phase displacement in AC circuits

Tags: ac, circuit-analysis

[image]

Z1, Z2(impedance) and the effective value of I2 is given. My question is whether I can assume phase displacement of the current I, let's say 0º. I can finish the analysis of the circuit easily this way. Can I assume this?

Comment: What is the exact wording of the exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using the data you have without any assumption, if (and this is not clear from what you said) the only thing you have to find is the *active* power provided by the voltage source, i.e. its average power.

Let's use phasors and let's assume all quantities are expressed using RMS values ("effective values"). As you may know the *complex power* \$S=P+jQ\$ (P and Q are the active and reactive power, respectively) absorbed by an impedance \$Z=R+jX\$ is given by:

$$
S = V \cdot I^*
$$

Where \$V\$ and \$I\$ are the voltage across \$Z\$ and the current through it, respectively. Using complex Ohm's law \$V=Z\cdot I\$ you can express S in two different ways:

\begin{align*}
S &= Z \cdot |I|^2 = (R+jX) \cdot |I|^2 \\[1 em]
S &= \dfrac {|V|^2} {Z^*} \; = \; \dfrac{R+jX}{R^2 + X^2} \cdot |V|^2
\end{align*}

From those formulas we can get the active power by considering only the real part of S:

\begin{align*}
P &= Re(S) = R \cdot |I|^2 \\[1 em]
P &= Re(S) = \dfrac{R}{R^2 + X^2} \cdot |V|^2
\end{align*}

We are interested in the active power \$P_s = Re(S_s)\$ provided by the source. We know from the conservation of energy, that it must be the sum of the active power absorbed by the two impedances:

$$
P_s = P_1 + P_2
$$

Since we know the RMS value of \$I_2\$, i.e. we know \$|I_2|\$, we can write:

$$
P_2 = R_2 \cdot |I_2|^2
\qquad\qquad
P_2 = \dfrac{R_2}{R_2^2 + X_2^2} \cdot |U|^2
$$

From those equations you can get \$P_2\$ and \$|U|^2\$. This latter allows to compute \$P_1\$ using the formula:

$$
P_1 = \dfrac{R_1}{R_1^2 + X_1^2} \cdot |U|^2
$$

As stated above, what you are looking for is \$P_s = P_1 + P_2\$.

Comment: Actually complex power across voltage source is needed. What I would really like to know is whether my assumption is sound. Phase displacement isn't given anywhere in the circuit, and when I assume phase displacement of one element, current I2, phase displacement of voltages and any other current, adjusts accordingly. So I get the right power. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Z1 = R1 + jX1; Z2 = R2 - jX2;
I=U/Z -> Z = Z1||Z2

You can't assume that phase displacement is 0, because it isn't. The only situation when phase is 0, is R1=R2 X1=X2.

Comment: I don't have the voltage U. When I change the phase displacement of current, phase d. of the voltage changes so that the power is the same. The assignment asks for power on the voltage source. It makes sense to me since no phase displacement is given anywhere.